# Dependency Property on a usercontrol that is bound to another VM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've run into the following problem:
I'm currently creating an on screen keyboard that is a usercontrol that has its own viewmodel.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="AlphaNumericKeyboard" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I'm attempting to add a dependency property called `KeyboardAlphaMode` that can be toggled by other view models that are using this usercontrol

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyboardAlphaModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeyboardAlphaMode", 
    typeof(UIKeyboardAlphaMode), typeof(AlphaNumericKeyboardView),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(UIKeyboardAlphaMode.LowerCase, new PropertyChangedCallback(KeyboardAlphaModeCallBack)));

    private static void KeyboardAlphaModeCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){ ... }
```

But, when I attempt to bind to this property from another view, the callback was never fired ..

```
    <k:AlphaNumericKeyboardView x:Name="alphaNumericKeyboard" KeyboardAlphaMode="{Binding KeyboardAlphaMode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </k:AlphaNumericKeyboardView>
```

What am I missing here? a setter? trigger?

Or this is just a thought, can a usercontrol that has dependency be bound to a viewmodel? or does it have to be bound to itself?

---

Edit - 10/10/2014 @ 1:31pm
After rethinking the entire solution i came up with the following scenario for my problem.
I binded the Dependency Property to the view's viewmodel and let the viewmodels interact with each other instead having other viewmodel talking to this specific view ...

Here's the code for that ..

```
    Binding alphaModeBinding = new Binding("KeyboardAlphaMode")
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
        TargetNullValue = UIKeyboardAlphaMode.LowerCase,
        FallbackValue = UIKeyboardAlphaMode.LowerCase
    };

    this.SetBinding(KeyboardAlphaModeProperty, alphaModeBinding);
```

I also made the dependency property protected so no one else can access it.
Unless there is a better way to track property changes, i'm sticking with this for now.

Again, not sure this is the best solution but it gets the job done.

---

Comment: Most likely binding context is invalid. Did you check output for binding errors? Does `DataContext` for `k:AlphaNumericKeyboardView` has `KeyboardAlphaMode` property?

Comment: Yes it does ... i'm not seeing any binding errors.

Comment: Is the binding producing a value that is *different from* the default value of `LowerCase`?  If the effective value of the property doesn't *actually change*, then the change callback will not be invoked.

Comment: Yes - it's actually changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Mode=TwoWay` on the binding.